# WCF has stopped since when I enabled the HTTP Activation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf, windows-10

I'm facing a weird behavior with `WCF`.
Some information about the environment:

- Windows 10
- VisualStudio 2015 Community
- One `ASP.NET Website` project
- One `WPF` project
- Both projects use `WCF` to talk

And here the steps I did:

1. Developed and tested the `WCF` communication with the VisualStudio debugger and IISExpress
2. Moved the website to IIS in order to serve external connections
3. The `WCF` communications raised this exception: exception of type 'System.Runtime.FatalException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
4. To fix this I had to enable `WCF HTTP Activation` in the Windows Features
5. It worked just once, then it stopped! I mean, I ran the application and the communication went well. Then I restarted it and the messages were not received anymore. I also rebooted the PC - no way.

I tried to set a breakpoint in the:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void ShowMessage(string message);
```

implementation (see below) and it doesn't hit. No exceptions, no errors.
Here is the code I've used to create an example `WCF` communication:

https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

I cannot understand why it worked once and then it stopped.
Of course, now I don't know what I should do to revert back it to work!